# Highcharts set yAxis labels width

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to set the labels width or other option, so the graph will not move/adjust when label's value is changed.

```
yAxis: {
        title: { text: '' },
        useHTML: true,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<div class="yAxisCustomLabel">' + moneySign + this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call({
                    axis: this.axis,
                    value: this.value
                }) + '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to make a custom class and add style, but no success, maybe because it's part of svg.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [marginLeft](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginLeft) which can give yAxis room enough.

Here is an example with maginLeft: 200;

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        borderWidth: 1,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        marginLeft: 200
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
     labels: {
       format: 'this is a very long label'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.x + ': ' + this.y;
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```